# Custom errormessage for property converter

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to use a ressource to set the errormessage on a property convert error?

```
[Range(0, 10, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
[DataMember]
public int MyProperty
{
  get; set;
}
```

The problem occourres if I try to set MyProperty to "aaa". I get an error saying "Cannot convert 'aaa'". It is that message that I wish to customize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. I have created an extention for the controls I use in my XAML code (typically a TextBox). In the extention I handle the format exception and find the appropriate resource.

Answer (score 0):

A really good way to do this would be within a Try/Catch statement. The following is in VB.net, as I'm not yet perfectly well versed in VB.

Try
'Your code for setting the property.
Catch
MessageBox.Show("Your error message text here", "Your Error Title Here", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
End Try

Basically, you are going to create a try/catch statement, with the code for setting the property under "Try". Then, under "Catch", you're going to show a message box.

Comment: I need to able to do it from XAML.